# Cross-Database Associations in Sequelize ORM

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have two DBs
Db1 is 'instance_db' and Db2 is 'system_db'.
In 'instance_db' I have models like person and in 'system_db' I have models like gender.
I have to join person model with gender model which in 'system_db'.
Below is my Code I am trying

// personModel

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

const Person = sequelize.define("person", {
id_psn: {
type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
autoIncrement: true,
primaryKey: true
         },
idsystem_gen_psn: {
type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
allowNull: true
         }
  })
return Person
}
```

// genderModel

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
 const Gender = sequelize.define("Gender", {
 idgender_gen: {
 autoIncrement: true,
 type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
 allowNull: false,
 primaryKey: true
   },
 ..
 is_deleted_gen: {
 type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
 allowNull: true,
 defaultValue: 0
   }
 
   }, {
 tableName: 'gender_gen', // Specify the existing table name here
 schema: "systemDb",
 freezeTableName: true, // Prevents Sequelize from renaming the table
 timestamps: false
   });
 
 return Gender
 }
```

// index.js

```
const dbConfig = require('../config/dbConfig.js');
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

// Create the first Sequelize instance for DB1
const sequelizeDB1 = new Sequelize(
    dbConfig.db1.DB,
    dbConfig.db1.USER,
    dbConfig.db1.PASSWORD, {
        host: dbConfig.db1.HOST,
        dialect: dbConfig.db1.dialect,
        pool: {
            max: dbConfig.db1.pool.max,
            min: dbConfig.db1.pool.min,
            acquire: dbConfig.db1.pool.acquire,
            idle: dbConfig.db1.pool.idle
        }
    }
);

// Create the second Sequelize instance for DB2
const sequelizeDB2 = new Sequelize(
    dbConfig.db2.DB,
    dbConfig.db2.USER,
    dbConfig.db2.PASSWORD, {
        host: dbConfig.db2.HOST,
        dialect: dbConfig.db2.dialect,
        pool: { 
            // You can use the same pool config or define a new one
            max: dbConfig.db2.pool.max,
            min: dbConfig.db2.pool.min,
            acquire: dbConfig.db2.pool.acquire,
            idle: dbConfig.db2.pool.idle
        }
    }
);

// Test connection for DB1
sequelizeDB1.authenticate()
.then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to DB1');
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log('Error connecting to DB1: ' + err)
});

// Test connection for DB2
sequelizeDB2.authenticate()
.then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to DB2');
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log('Error connecting to DB2: ' + err)
});

const db = {}

// Add Sequelize instances to the db object
db.sequelizeDB1 = sequelizeDB1;
db.sequelizeDB2 = sequelizeDB2;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

// Import models for DB1

db.persons = require('./personModel.js')(sequelizeDB1, DataTypes);

// Sync DB1 (do not force in production)
sequelizeDB1.sync({ force: false })
.then(() => {
    console.log('Sync for DB1 done!')
    console.log('db.persons-'+db.persons)
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log('Error occurred during DB1 sync: ', err);
});

// Import models for DB2
// Let's say we have otherModel.js as a separate model for DB2
db.genders = require('../system_models/genderModel.js')(sequelizeDB2, DataTypes);


// Optionally, sync DB2 (do not force in production)
sequelizeDB2.sync({ force: false })
.then(() => {
    console.log('Sync for DB2 done!')
    console.log('db.genders-'+db.genders)
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log('Error occurred during DB2 sync: ', err);
});

require('./associations.js')(db);

module.exports = db;
```

// associations.js

```
module.exports = (db) => {
    // Your association logic here
    db.persons.belongsTo(db.genders, {
        foreignKey: 'idsystem_gen_psn', 
        as: 'gender'            
      });
  
    // ... any other associations
  };
```

When I execute it I am getting error as
original: Error: Table 'instance_db.system_db.gender' doesn't exist.
But If I just do query for gender table its working.

Comment: Sequelize instances do not aware of each other existence and their models and more over cross-DB queries could be written not in any DB and only with special functions.